# How does uwsgi cache non-text/html content?

Tags: uwsgi

Can somebody explain how the following snippet from [the uwsgi docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/CachingCookbook.html) works?

```
cache2 = name=mycache,items=100
; load the mime types engine
mime-file = /etc/mime.types

; at each request starting with /img check it in the cache (use mime types engine for the content type)
route = ^/img/(.+) cache:key=/img/$1,name=mycache,mime=1

; at each request ending with .css check it in the cache
route = \.css$ cache:key=${REQUEST_URI},name=mycache,content_type=text/css

; fallback to text/html all of the others request
route = .* cache:key=${REQUEST_URI},name=mycache

; store each successful request (200 http status code) in the 'mycache' cache using the REQUEST_URI as key
route = .* cachestore:key=${REQUEST_URI},name=mycache
```

Since ${REQUEST_URI} is used for storing everything in the cache, but only a part of ${REQUEST_URI} is used to check the cache for images, how is this supposed to work? I did output ${REQUEST_URI} with the log: routing target, and it equals the complete request starting from the first / every time.

Something similar in my setup does not work (I am using /usr/local/etc/nginx/mime.types as the mime types file).

Thanks,
t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at this line:

```
route = ^/img/(.+) cache:key=/img/$1,name=mycache,mime=1
```

It will catch all requests for files inside `/img/` directory, saving it's path relative to `/img/` in variable `$1`. Now it asks cache for key `/img/$1`, so it will glue `/img/` at the beginning of saved path.

For file `/img/my_logo.png` it will save "my_logo.png" in `$1` variable, then it will glue "/img/" at the beginning of saved path, so at the end, it will query for `/img/my_logo.png`.

Basically, it re-creates `REQUEST_URI`. So if it doesn't work for you, make sure that you're using same base directory name in regex and in cache key.